# How can i check that 2 dates between period(month)

Tags: java, date

i have 2 Date (`start_date`, `end_date`) with yyyy-MM-dd format and i want to check that if the month between in december 01 - march 31 then do something. For example my `start_date` is 2015-12-01 or 2016-02-01 and `end_date` 2016-02-12 then write something.
I have this

```
public void meethod(){
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
     Date startDate = null;
     Date endDate = null;

     try {
         startDate = df.parse(tf_start_date.getText());
         endDate = df.parse(tf_end_date.getText());
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     if( /* what goes here? */ ) {
        System.out.println("its between december-march");
     } else {

     }
 }
```

`tf_start_date` and `tf_end_date` is a TextField and the value of TextFields like 2015-02-03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should probably be using `Calendar` rather than `Date`. First, you'll need to construct the `Calendar` using a `Calendar.Builder`:

```
Calendar startCal = Calendar.Builder().setInstant(startDate);
Calendar endCal = Calendar.Builder().setInstant(endDate);
```

Then you can just check their months to see if they are one of the months you're looking for:

```
int startMonth = startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
if (startMonth == Calendar.DECEMBER ||
    startMonth == Calendar.JANUARY ||
    startMonth == Calendar.FEBRUARY ||
    startMonth == Calendar.MARCH)
```

Similarly with `endMonth`.